# LSTM using Keras, dimension error of input fed to the first layer

Tags: python, keras

as said above I have a problem with the input data dimension in my LSTM network, which gave me the next error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

My code:

```
input_data = Input((20,))
z = Embedding(5000, input_length=20, output_dim=80, 
weights[embedding_matrix])(input_data)

#z:(?,25,100)->(batch_size?,25-sentence length,100-embedding_size)

z = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(z)
z = LSTM(256,return_sequences=True)(inputs)
z = LSTM(128)(z)
z = Dense(64, activation='relu')(z)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(z)

model = Model(input_data,out)
```

I'm getting the error in the first LSTM layer.

I know that the problem is the `"?"` in `axis=0`, tried to solve this.
Those are the things I tried:

1. Inspired by this solution:
   ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721810/lstm-keras-value-input-dimension-error"](http://%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721810/lstm-keras-value-input-dimension-error%22)

   x = x.reshape(1, x.shape[0], x.shape[1](http://%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721810/lstm-keras-value-input-dimension-error%22))

   But I got this error:

   > IndexError: tuple index out of range
2. Also Tried:

   > x = np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)

   But didn't because the types didn't match.

I tried a few more solutions but with no luck, I'll be happy if someone can help me figure it out.

Thanks!!

Comment: You are passing `inputs` to the LSTM. Pass `z` instead.

Comment: OMG!
Thanks, and sorry for that!